# java.lang IllegalArgumentException

Tags: storage, adoptable-storage

When trying to set up a S5 for adoptable storage with 6.0.1 opp sys. When I put in the `sm list` disks command I get a list of sm commands and an error.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

The command is `sm list-disks` instead of `sm list disks`.

Comment: Put small answers as comment.

Comment: I feel stupid now but Thank You so much.